# How to correctly match the start and end of any word with exactly the same sequence while having characters in between?

Tags: regex

I am using UNIX and Regex to match any word with the same sequence at start and end. Plus, it has to have one specific character (say 'm') followed by any number of characters in between.

For instances:

**ca**hello**mca** is valid

**sa**lo**m**more**sa** is valid

**lo**noletter**lo** not valid

**hom**last**ho** is valid

Here is what I have been able to do. However, it returns zero for a list with the previous words (it should return 3).

```
% egrep -c '^([a-z]{2})(z{1}.*)\2\1$' list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single capture group at the start.

Then match the char like `m` surrounded by optional chars `[a-z]*` and use the backreference at the end of the string.

```
^([a-z]+)[a-z]*m[a-z]*\1$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Cadt2/1)

Example

```
egrep -c '^([a-z]+)[a-z]*m[a-z]*\1$' list
```

Output

```
3
```

---

Or as suggested by @[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)

```
grep -cE '^([a-z]+)[a-z]*m[a-z]*\1$' list
```

Comment: ++ but avoid `egrep` as it is deprecated. `grep -cE` is preferred

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, I did not know that it is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. They we're helpful to understand what I was doing wrong.